# Handling resource not found on react router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I have the following routing schema:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" exact render={DashboardPage}/>
  <Route path="/accounts/:id" exact render={AccountPage} />
</Router>

const AccountPage = (props) => {
  const {match: {params}} = props;
  const id = _.toInteger(params.id);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <AccountComponent id={id}/>
    </Layout>
  )
};
```

I have all the existing accounts already in the store, so there's no need to do an Ajax call to confirm existence. 
My question is: how do I handle the case where the id doesn't match any existing resource ?

Comment: I think you need to handle this in your `AccountPage` component and if the `id` doesn't exist, redirect to a not found URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the existence of the id in the `componentDidMount` of the AccountPage so if id doesn't exist it should redirect to somewhere else or show him another content so your code should be something like this :

```
export default class AccountPage extends Component { 
  componentDidMount(){
    const {match: {params}} = props;
    const id = _.toInteger(params.id);

    //existenceCheck is a function that will check the id existence  
    if(existenceCheck(id)) {
      this.props.history.push('/not-found')
    }
  }

  //render and etc
}
```